# Golang Pointers as method param

Tags: pointers, go

I am working with golang's pointers the way I did with c++, but it seems not to work, which would be the right way to do it? or what am I doing wrong?, Thanks.

ftw I'm doing AsyncBinaryTrees.

```
type Obj interface {
    Compare(node Obj) int
}

type Tree struct {
    Item        Obj
    Rigth, Left *Tree
    height      int16
}

func Insert(t *Tree, item Obj) chan struct{} {
    done := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    go insert(t, item, done)
    return done
}

func insert(t *Tree, item Obj, done chan struct{}) {
    if t == nil {
        t = &Tree{Item: nil, Rigth: nil, Left: nil, height: 0}
        var signal struct{}
        done <- signal
        close(done)
    } else {
        if t.Item.Compare(item) == 1 { //Left
            insert(t.Left, item, done)
        } else if t.Item.Compare(item) == -1 { //Rigth
            insert(t.Right, item, done)
        } else {
            close(done)
            panic
        }
    }
}

//=== testing

func assertSignal(ch_signal chan struct{}, t *testing.T) {
    _, done := <-ch_signal
    if !done {
        t.Error("Error: it should send a signal of empty struct")
    }
}

func TestInsertion(t *testing.T) {
    var tree *Tree
    ch_signal := Insert(tree, newObjInt())
    fmt.PrintLn(t)             //=> <nil>
    assertSignal(ch_signal, t) //=>PASS
    ch_signal = Insert(tree, newObjInt())
    fmt.PrintLn(t)             //=> <nil>
    assertSignal(ch_signal, t) //=>PASS
    ch_signal = Insert(tree, newObjInt())
    fmt.PrintLn(t)             //=> <nil>
    assertSignal(ch_signal, t) //=>PASS
    ch_signal = Insert(tree, newObjInt())
    assertSignal(ch_signal, t) //=>PASS
}
```

nil

nil

nil

TEST PASS

Comment: What is not working? Well, except for obvious things like calling `insert(t.Left, done)` to a function that takes three arguments.

Comment: And closing done without sending any signal.

Comment: typo error i did a checkout so i replicate the error here, and i'm closing the channel because the item already exist so there is no signal of done

Comment: You have to initialize your Tree struct first: replace `var tree *Tree` with `tree := new(Tree)`. Pointers are passed by values, so struct initialization from inside methods won't work as you expect it to: new reference (`t = &Tree`) won't leave method scope. See the illustration: http://play.golang.org/p/X33zMW7Nxh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `insert` function you have:

```
func insert(t *Tree, item Obj, done chan struct{}) {
    if t == nil {
        t = &Tree{Item: nil, Rigth: nil, Left: nil, height: 0}
    ...
}
```

This updates the local variable `t`, but will not change the variable passed in the calling scope since Go passes function parameters by value.  So when you make the following call:

```
insert(t.Left, item, done)
```

if `t.Left` is `nil`, its value will not be changed by the function call.  If you do want it to update the variable, you'll need to define the function argument as `t **Tree`, change references to set `*t` instead, and change the call to:

```
insert(&t.Left, item, done)
```

There is no equivalent to C++'s syntax for passing function arguments by reference: instead you need to be explicit when passing pointers.